Does the set of antiderivatives of $tan(x)$ have uncountable dimension?
On a connected domain, the set of antiderivatives of a continuous function $f$ is $1$-dimensional. However, for a punctured domain like $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, the set of antiderivatives becomes $2$-dimensional. I wonder, what about a domain with countably many holes, like the domain of $tan(x)$? Is it countably-infinite dimensional, or uncountable dimensional?

Why $2$-dimensional ? An antiderivate of $\tan(x)$ is still a single function and the set of antiderivates is $F(x)+c$ with any real number $c$ , if $F'(x)=\tan(x)$. This is still $1$-dimensional.

The dimension of the space of antiderivatives will always match the number of connected components of the domain. In this case it’ll be countably infinite.

@Peter The constant $c$ may be different on each connected component.

@SimonPitte OK , now I understand the point.
